# Why does parseInt remove the underscore

Tags: javascript

When I try to parse some string type numeric value like so:

```
a = parseInt("5")
```

Then `a` is equal to `5`.

If I try to parse a string like so:

```
a = parseInt("A")
```

Then my answer is `NaN`.

But, when I try to parse this:

```
a = parseInt("1492515425322_1")
```

Then `a` is equal to `1492515425322`.

Why it is not `NaN`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: "If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point."

Comment: let's talk about javascript....https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: That's how parsing functions work in many languages. I presume that if they were stricter they wouldn't be different from plain type casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it will basically try to parse the string and will return you all the numbers before `_`. If  you want to know if the entire string is a number you could use `Number("1492515425322_1")` and it will return NaN.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

So `parseInt()` will parse the string up until it encounters anything that's not numeric, and ignore the rest.  With `"A"` the very first character was non-numeric, so nothing could be parsed at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's documented behaviour:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses
>   it, and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will
>   be the integer that is the first argument taken as a number in the
>   specified radix (base).